# Is there a render engine with complete GPU support and Blender integration

Tags: rendering, performance

Is there any rendering engine for Blender that only uses the GPU?

I know that Cycles and Luxrender can do this but not all materials work
In gpu mode. So what I am asking is are there any rendering engines which are able to render exclusively on the gpu.

Comment: I use nvidia cuda with cycles, and it works great.

Comment: What's flu mode? And what problems are you hoping for the engine to deal with?

Comment: Flu mode is wat auto correct thinks gpu mode is

Comment: What materials specifically? I can't think of any shaders that are unsupported in the most recent build (2.74), at least not right off of the top of my head.

Comment: Sub surface scattering in cycles and just about all costume materials in luxrender

Comment: @SupaKoopaTroopa64 SSS is supported on GPU when *experimental features* are enabled. It's always worked fine for me.

Comment: Here's a compatibility table which shows what features are currently supported on what: http://blender.org/manual/render/cycles/features.html

Comment: The only real issue with GPU rendering right now is how much memory your card has. Limits how many image textures you can use as well as how many polygons your scene can have.

Answer (score 1):

Octane Render is the world’s first GPU based, un-biased, physically based renderer. Octane Render runs exclusively on Nvidia's CUDA technology.

You can check on Wikipedia:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octane_Render